# Apache2 virtual host default for direct IP connection

Tags: php, apache

I have installed Apache2 on my Ubuntu server running virtual host for different domains, with the IP address like "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx". How do I force the client to reach destinated page or even block them from visiting my webserver when they browse my webpages through my IP "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"? (i.e. I do not want them to surf my server using only the IP instead of my domains.)

Comment: why is it a problem that they connect to you by IP?

Answer (score 0):

In Apache, first `VirtualHost` definition is used when connecting with host which doesn't match any `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`.

So just add extra `VirtualHost` definition before all others, and then do whatever you want there (always give 404 error, show error-page, ...)